# Как сделать вложенные компоненты используя связку React и Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Есть желание сделать вложенные компоненты используя стек React и Typescript

Под вложенными компонентами я подразумеваю возможность использования компонента как по основному default пути, так и через точечную нотацию

Например:

```
<Menu><Menu.Item>первый пункт меню</Menu.Item></Menu>
```

Если есть возможность, приведите пример реализации подобного компонента

Заранее спасибо за ваши ответы

Ответ:

```
const Menu: React.FC & {Item: typeof Item} = ({
  children,
}) => (
  <div>
    {children}
  </div>
);

Menu.Item = ({
  children
}) => (
  <span>
    {children}
  </span>
);

const App = () => (
  <Menu>
    <Menu.Item>Item 1</Menu.Item>
    <Menu.Item>Item 2</Menu.Item>
    <Menu.Item>Item 3</Menu.Item>
  </Menu>
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
const Menu = ({
  children,
}) => (
  <div>
    {children}
  </div>
);

Menu.Item = ({
  children
}) => (
  <span>
    {children}
  </span>
);

const App = () => (
  <Menu>
    <Menu.Item>Item 1</Menu.Item>
    <Menu.Item>Item 2</Menu.Item>
    <Menu.Item>Item 3</Menu.Item>
  </Menu>
);
```

Для тайпскрипта только добавить типы:

```
const Menu = ({ children }: PropsWithChildren<{}>) => (
  <div>
    {children}
  </div>
);

Menu.Item = ({ children }: PropsWithChildren<{}>) => (
  <span>
    {children}
  </span>
);

const App = () => (
  <Menu>
    <Menu.Item>Item 1</Menu.Item>
    <Menu.Item>Item 2</Menu.Item>
    <Menu.Item>Item 3</Menu.Item>
  </Menu>
);
```

Comment: О, круто! Я почему-то считал, что нельзя функциям просто так свойства докидывать. Но скопировал это в ts и в принципе работает, только надо тип параметров указать `PropsWithChildren<{}>`.

Comment: Спасибо, ваш вариант подошел. но пришлось его заточить под ts, в своем вопросе выложу код

Comment: @user447630, во-первых, ответы надо писать в ответах, а не в вопросе, во-вторых, ты что-то перемудрил.

Comment: @ТрипольскийПётр, я добавил ts-версию в твой ответ - не против?

Answer (score 1):

```
function Outer({ children }: PropsWithChildren<{}>) {
  return <div>{children}</div>
}

namespace Outer {
  export function Inner() {
    return <span>inner</span>
  }
}

function Smth() {
  return (
    <Outer>
      <Outer.Inner />
    </Outer>
  )
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, ваш вариант хороший, но у нас в проекте в правилах запрещено использовать namespace

Comment: @user447630, соседний вариант действительно лучше. Я думал, что ts не позволит просто так присваивать левые свойства функциям, поэтому нахимичил модуль. А раз он позволяет, то надо просто там типы дописать и всё.